# Flutter Error : invalid source release: 17

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> error: invalid source release: 17

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Solution is : just add this line to gradle.properties:

org.gradle.java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

I hope you find this solution is useful

Regards

Comment: Please add the solution as a separate comment and accept the answer.

Comment: The user added a solution inside the question. Suggested to add as a separate comment and accept it as the solution.